# JavaScript Проверка на аргумент-undefined

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. Тема: *«Псевдомассив аргументов "arguments"»*.

**Задача из учебника:**

> Как в функции отличить отсутствующий аргумент от undefined?
>
> ```html
> function f(x) {
>   // ..ваш код..
>   // выведите 1, если первый аргумент есть, и 0 - если нет
> }
>
> f(undefined); // 1
> f(); // 0
> ```

**Ответ из учебника:**

> Узнать количество реально переданных аргументов можно по значению arguments.length:
>
> ```html
> function f(x) {
>   alert( arguments.length ? 1 : 0 );
> }
>
> f(undefined);
> f();
> ```

Меня конечно такой ответ не очень устроил, т.к. я хотел видеть результат получения ноля, когда отсутствует первый аргумент, но присутствуют другие.

**Вот, что мне хочется получить:**

```js
  // выведите 1, если первый аргумент есть, и 0 - если нет
'use strict';

function f(x, a, b) {
  // code
}

f(undefined);     // Получить 1
f();              // Получить 0
f('', 78, 'abc'); // Получить 0
```

т.е. когда первый "отсутствующий", но есть другие, чтобы выдавал 0.

**1).** **Мой первый вопрос**, терминология. В моем варианте **f('', 78, 'abc');** Первый аргумент назывется "отсутствующий" или нет?

---

В поисках решения,я пытался записать так:

```js
alert((arguments[0]).length ? 1 : 0);

alert(arguments[0].length ? 1 : 0);
```

Но видимо такая запись некорректная и я решил действовать основательно, много думал и в итоге, вот мое решение в одну строку:

```js
'use strict';

function f(x, a, b) {
  arguments.length ? console.log(arguments[0] === '' ? 0 : 1) : console.log(0);
}

f(undefined);     //  1
f();              //  0
f('', 78, 'abc'); //  0
```

Все, что хотел, я получил, теперь отсутствующий аргумент отличаем от *undefined*; получаем **0**, когда первый отсутствующий и других нет, и когда первый отсутствующий,но есть другие.

**2).** **Мой второй вопрос.** Как вам мой код? Возможно я что-то упустил или есть более оптимальная запись.

Comment: Аргумент не является отсутствующим, если вы что-то указали в списке аргументов. В этом вызове функции f('', 78, 'abc'); задаеы три аргумента.

Comment: Как он тогда называется в данном случае, если не "отсутствующий"?

Comment: Это пустой строковый литерал.

Comment: Можно ли тогда в моем примере сделать первый отсутствующий, но чтобы были другие(возможно через другую запись) или это невозможно? Мне желательно с примерами, т.к. я пока еще не спец во всех терминах.

Comment: Вы могли бы представить этот вызов иначе. Например, var s = ''; f( s, 78, 'abc' ); Здесь более наглядно видно, что имеется три аргумента.

Comment: Можно опускать "хвостовые" аргументы.

Comment: Последний комментарий мне не понятен. **1).** Вот такой простой пример `var arr = [];  arr[10] = 5;  alert(arr);` Здесь значения до 10, также не отсутствуют, а являются пустыми строковыми литералами? **2).** Я пытался так записать `f('abc', , 'abc');` но выдает ошибку; никакая подобная запись здесь не предусмотрена? Это я по аналогии с массивом `var arr= ["one", , "more"];alert(arr);`

Comment: Нельзя пропускать значения аргументов.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Объект `arguments` не является массивом. Он формируется на основании того, как вызвана функция, и содержит все аргумента вызова (вне зависимости от сигнатуры функции в ее декларации) в том порядке, в котором они указаны в вызове - без пропусков. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov "Я пытался так записать `f('abc', , 'abc');`" - `f('abc', undefined, 'abc');` - максимум, что мы можем для Вас сделать :)